# Firebase SDK Auth issue with Google 2FA

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We are currently using Firebase SDK Auth in both a web app, and an iOS app.  We have sign-in with email & password working fine, and sign-in with Google works as long as the Google account doesn't have their 2-step verification enabled.  With Google 2-step verification, rather than logging-in after authorizing access, it goes back to a previous page in the login process, and seems to get stuck in some sort of loop.  Sometimes it will login on a second attempt, but this is obviously not a good user experience.

Is there something we need to know about working with accounts that have Google 2-step verification enabled, in Firebase SDK Auth?  The documentation doesn't mention anything about it.

Comment: I have similar issue, sign in works but I don't get email from account with 2FA. Did you have something new on this issue?

Comment: @DavidVávra After posting this question, I found an issue on Github about this.  Someone from the Firebase team commented that the Auth SDK doesn't support Google 2SV.  The issue hasn't been updated in about a year and a half, so I really have no idea what the status is currently.

Comment: Can you send me link to the issue?